# Streaming server issue with gunicorn and flask and Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, streaming, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn and flask for a web service. I am trying to get my head around running a streaming route (not sure if that is the correct terminology).

my route looks like this:

```
@app.route('/delay')
def delay():
    from time import sleep
    def delay_inner():
        for i in range(10):
            sleep(5)
            yield json.dumps({'delay': i})
    return Response(delay_inner(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

I expect that the server would yield the output each time that delay_inner does a yield. But, what I am getting is all the json responses at once, and only when the delay_inner finishes execution.

What am I missing here?

--EDIT--
I have fixed the issue for Flask and Gunicorn, I am able to run it as expected by using the flask server, and by going to the Gunicorn port. It streams the data as expected. However, and I should have mentioned this in the original post, I am also running behind nginx. And that is not set up correctly to stream. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: I would suggest you also post your NGINX config if you believe that to be the problem.

Comment: Have you played with http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to turn off the nginx proxy buffering.

```
location /delay {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
         proxy_buffering off;
}
```

and reload the config

```
nginx -s reload
```

Comment: Thank you ! It fixed my problem !

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!